# WCF Data Services EntityFramework Provider - still in development?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

we are currently evaluating a MVVM Toolkit, which seems to rely on "WCF Data Services EntityFramework Provider" (nuget link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider/1.0.0-alpha1)

The last update was in October 2013, Version 1.0.0 alpha1.

This is at least suspicious, so - my question: is this component still actively developed, or has it been superseded by some new MS-product?

Regards
Johannes Colmsee

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has been abandoned.  ODATA has replaced WCF Data Services in general.